# SQL Server 2005 Isolation level changes on service restart, how to stop it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Whenever I change the isolation level from read committed to re uncommitted. Then I restart the SQL Server Service (2005) it will reset the isolation level back to read committed.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? (changing the value on restart of SQL Server)

Comment: Do you have any data tables or replications in that data base?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isolation level can only be set within a connection. Simply reconnecting and it will change it back to the default. An application should always **explicitly** set the desired isolation level if not happy with the default. The default cannot be changed.

That being said, read uncommitted is never a good isolation level, because it produces [inconsistent results](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx). Whenever an application abuses the uncommitted isolation level is an indication of an access problem (like missing indexes leading to table scans).

Answer (score 3):

Isolation level is set per transaction, not per server or database.
You therefore must declare your isolation level every time you make a connection to the server.

More reading: [Customizing Transaction Isolation Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175909.aspx).